# Update MySQL with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

It seems I have big problems with *conditional queries*.

I have to do a *conditional update*. I write here what I would like to do:

```
 IF(SELECT tipo FROM abbonamento WHERE idU = 17) = 'punti' THEN
     UDPATE abbonamento SET punti = punti - 1 
 ELSE
     UPDATE abbonamento SET bonus = bonus - 1
```

Obviously this doesn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

`MySQL` supports `IF` statement.

```
UPDATE  abbonamento
SET     punti = IF(tipo = 'punti', punti - 1, punti),
        bonus = IF(tipo <> 'punti', bonus - 1, bonus)
WHERE   id = 17
```

or you can also use `CASE`

```
UPDATE  abbonamento
SET     punti = CASE WHEN tipo = 'punti' THEN punti - 1 ELSE punti END,
        bonus = CASE WHEN tipo <> 'punti' THEN bonus - 1 ELSE bonus END
WHERE   id = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote will work fine, but unfortunately, you misspelled the work update to `UDPATE` . that's why it is not working. check-in your if.