# update remaining balance to 0 if payment is greater than remaining balance

Tags: php, sql

using this query i can easily deduct the payment to the remaining balance

let say that my rem_balance is 3000  and my payment is 5000 so basically the change would be 2000.

```
UPDATE tbl_users SET rem_balance = (rem_balance - '5000') WHERE user_id = '2017001002'
```

but since i use this query what happen is the rem_balance updates to -2000 what i wanted to achieve is that if payment is `>` rem_balance, rem_balance becomes 0 and it will separate the change.

Comment: add tag of DBMS you are using

Comment: im using mysql as my db. and php as my language

Comment: You can use IF condition . like : SET rem_balance = IF(),

Comment: Use a `case` expression.

Comment: refere link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001217/update-mysql-with-if-condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
UPDATE tbl_users 
SET rem_balance = (CASE WHEN rem_balance < 5000 THEN 0 ELSE rem_balance - 5000 END)
WHERE user_id = '2017001002'
```

Please be aware of the fact that you use implicit conversion in your SQL ('5000' instead of 5000). It is a bad habit and it can harm performance of your queries in certain cases. For example, if `tbl_users.user_id` is integer as well then the update will be unable to use indexes to search the row with the specific `user_id` and it will do a sequential scan which is very slow.

Comment: is there a possibility on this query to get the change of rem_balance < 5000 like return the remaining value?.

Comment: @LionSmith I'm not sure what you are asking. You want the remaining balance to be returned?

Comment: nahh.. this is exactly what i ask.. my comment is just a question based on your answer..

Comment: @LionSmith I think that it is not possible in one query. You need to run `SELECT` after update to retrieve the new `rem_balance` value.